# Saving image in application documents

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I try to save a image from camera or photo album into application directory. But i cant find what i'm doing wrong.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
theimageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];       

//obtaining saving path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"latest_photo.png"];

//extracting image from the picker and saving it
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];  
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
    UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
    [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];


    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath];
    if(fileExists){
        NSLog(@"image Exists");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Describe what problem you are having.

Comment: Why is it returning false? If i test if the file exists?

Comment: I don't see any obvious mistakes in the code. just confirm if you have "latest_photo.png" file in the documents directory.

Comment: Nope i cant find anything in Documents..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use,

```
UIImage *orgImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

And where are failing? Did you get the image properly? or failing to write to document directory?

Comment: ye getting the image isnt a problem. I show it in a UIImageView, but i cant save it in application documents..

Comment: Nvm Your great it was i stupid copy past mistake..               UIImage *orgImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];    did it:)

Comment: @Th3noon maybe you should accept this as an answer? just click the tick mark underneath the score...

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file in fact exist in file explorer. Maybe the compiler is right.

Comment: thnx for your help.. I fixed it:)